# MySQL - Select to retrieve last datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table in MySQL:

```
| period_duration    | duration | sample | corner | country | partner       | ok_rate
+---------------------+----------+--------+----------+---------+-----------------------+-------------------------
| 2014-12-15 17:00:00 | 3600     | 1      | GRPS_INB | ARG     | Charlie   |     98   | 
| 2014-12-15 17:00:00 | 3600     | 1      | GRPS_INB | DEU     | Jack      |    90    |
| 2014-12-15 17:00:00 | 3600     | 1      | GRPS_INB | NLD     | Will      |    100   |
| 2014-12-15 20:00:00 | 3600     | 1      | GRPS_INB | ARG     | Charlie   |     98   |
| 2014-12-15 20:00:00 | 3600     | 1      | GRPS_INB | DEU     | Jack      |     90   |
| 2014-12-15 20:00:00 | 3600     | 1      | GRPS_INB | NLD     | Will      |    100   |

+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| period_duration | datetime    | NO   | PRI | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| duration        | varchar(6)  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| sample          | varchar(2)  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| corner          | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| country         | varchar(60) | NO   | PRI |                     |       |
| partner         | varchar(60) | NO   | PRI |                     |       |
| ok_rate         | int(8)      | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

This table increases from hour to hour.
I need a shellscript that will check each line from the last hour and that has an "ok_rate" lower than a given value, and return them to me on a select.
The select should bring country, the partner, and the ok_rate.

Example:

Let's say I want it to be done with <=98%¨on "ok_rate".
My returning rows would be:

```
| 2014-12-15 20:00:00 | 3600     | 1      | GRPS_INB | ARG     | Charlie   |     98   |
| 2014-12-15 20:00:00 | 3600     | 1      | GRPS_INB | DEU     | Jack      |     90   |
```

So far, I could only make it bring me the values below 98%, but not those that are also the last datetime that exists:

```
select country, partner, ok_rate from TABLE where ok_rate <= '98'
```

But how can I add a WHERE clause the makes it understand I want the last existing `datetime` that exists on `period_duration` too?

I mean something like:

`SELECT country, partner, ok_rate FROM TABLE WHERE pdp_in_ok_rate <=98 AND (period_duration IS  THE LAST ONE)`?

Comment: If you want it to be a period - why don't you store 2 dates: beginning and end? Then you could use `BETWEEN`

Comment: I don't control this table that much. I need to work on it like it is right now :/

Comment: What is duration measured in?

Comment: Use `ok_rate <= 98` instead of `<= '98'` - it is integer.

Comment: Why don't you simply order by period_duration and limit the result set to 1? If it cannot happen that there are more records with the same period duration and ok_rate, or just one is enough in the result set, this should work; otherwise it can be more tricky...

Comment: Just clarifying, do you want all of the last hour AND ALSO any rows with ok_rate <= 98,  or do you want ONLY the rows in the last hour which have ok_rate <= 98?

Comment: I want both. The problem with 'limit 1' is: how can I limit ONLY the last datetime???

Comment: I edited my post, maybe you could help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should return what you want:

```
SELECT country, partner, ok_rate
FROM TABLE WHERE ok_rate <= 98
AND period_duration = (SELECT MAX(period_duration)
                       FROM TABLE)
```

Comment: nope it wont, but you are in the right direction. Actually..after thinking about it, this wont work...MAX (time) won't be guarantee to be match the where condition

Comment: Fist time I heard that. Can you explain why?

Comment: for instance, if the condition is < 50 and the latest entry satisfies the condition is 2014-12-15 12:00:00, MAX(period_duration) would return 2014-12-15 20:00:00

Comment: I want the datetime that is closer to it, not that EQUALS it!

Comment: You need a **correlated** sub-query

Answer (score 0):

Look in to `GROUP BY` for more detail because I'm not exactly sure what you want but something like this should help:

```
SELECT country, partner, ok_rate FROM TABLE 
WHERE ok_rate <= '98'
GROUP BY `partner`, `country` 
HAVING period_duration = MAX(period_duration);
```

Comment: aggregate cant be used inside where

Comment: and I think you need to put the MAX inside select, and include ok_rate in the GROUP BY for this to compile, correct me if im wrong

Comment: `ok_rate` might not be from the same record