# MySQL - Average % value from last day insertions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got a table in MySQL:

```
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| period_duration | datetime    | NO   | PRI | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| duration        | varchar(6)  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| sample          | varchar(2)  | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| corner          | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| country         | varchar(60) | NO   | PRI |                     |       |
| roaming_partner | varchar(60) | NO   | PRI |                     |       |
| pdp_in_total    | int(8)      | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| pdp_in_ok       | int(8)      | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| pdp_in_not_ok   | int(8)      | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| pdp_in_ok_rate  | int(8)      | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

This table has new insertions hourly, that makes many different `period_duration` per `roaming_partner`:

```
+---------------------+----------+--------+----------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| period_duration     | duration | sample | corner   | country | roaming_partner       | pdp_in_total | pdp_in_ok | pdp_in_not_ok | pdp_in_ok_rate |
+---------------------+----------+--------+----------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| 2014-12-16 14:00:00 | 3600     | 1      | GPRS_OUT | USA     | Operator1             |          796 |       787 |             9 |             99 |
| 2014-12-16 15:00:00 | 3600     | 1      | GPRS_OUT | USA     | Operator1             |         1748 |      1706 |            42 |             98 |
| 2014-12-16 16:00:00 | 3600     | 1      | GPRS_OUT | USA     | Operator1             |            7 |         7 |             0 |            100 |
```

"ok_rate" is a percentage rate.

I need to create a `SELECT` that will show every single `country`, `roaming_partner` and `pdp_in_ok_rate` from the last 24 insertions, with the average `pdp_in_ok_rate`% from these insertions.

It is like i wanted that my SQL query say:
"This is the average pdp_in_ok_rate in the last 24 insertions for every operator on your table. Not in the whole table, but from these last ones."

Can someone please help me?

Comment: averages of averages don't make much sense. if one record has 1000 inserts successfull and a 100% average, and the other record has 2 inserts, of which one insert failed, then you've got avg(100%, 50%) = 75%, rather than 1001/1002 = 99.9% successful.

Comment: I use this to maintain daily averages, for network monitoring purposes. If I use your logic, after a given high-number of 100%s, every low percentage is gonna pass by undetected... I need to see averages based on a daily logic.

Comment: Could be irrelevant, but here's [another question of the same author](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494394/mysql-select-to-retrieve-last-datetime).

Comment: Guys, I don't get what you want by doing this, but ok... Let me say what I need. On the question you mentioned, I asked for help on a test database, and the problem was diferent. I could not find rows where a given clause was the newest, and it worked when one guy answered it using the MAX() function. I am new to this MySQL thing, but my problem is very different now. If you don't think someone's else doubts are relevant, make us a favor and don't say that things "don't make sense". It goes against what Stack Overflow is.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select country, roaming_partner, avg(pd_in_ok_rate) as avgrate
from table t
where period_duration >= date_sub(now(), interval -1 day)
group by country, roaming_partner;
```

This doesn't give you the detail on the average.  You can use this as a subquery, if you want the detail as well

```
select t.*, cr.avgrate
from table t join
     (select country, roaming_partner, avg(pd_in_ok_rate) as avgrate
      from table t
      where period_duration >= date_sub(now(), interval -1 day)
      group by country, roaming_partner
     ) cr
     on t.country = cr.country and t.roaming_partner = cr.roaming_partner
where period_duration >= date_sub(now(), interval -1 day);
```

Comment: No, it doens't... I don't want an average on the whole table, only on those that where captured is the last day! Imagine you have 24 percentages a day, and want to know their average every day, but without droping their values from the table

Comment: If I use this query, I might get an average on the whole table... My wish is to have only the last ones

Comment: It must be hard, I imagine :/

Comment: @ZeldaElf . . . The addition of the `where` clause seems to be the least important part of the approach, but I just added it in.